# Terraform - check if resource is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm attempting to figure out if there's a way to check if a resources is already created or enabled vi terraform, and if so, not to have terraform preform the resource creation. My issue is that there was no constancy when the AWS resources were built as it was done all manually, and I don't want to recreate resources or attempt to enable resource/services if they have been preformed/created. So I'm wondering if there is a way, I can find if a resource has been created or enabled, and skip that. For example, is there a way to check if CloudTrail already present or if Guardduty enabled or if Config enabled. I have multiple accounts, and can't go through them manually, and trying to find a programmatic way of doing this. I know I can use "count" but I need to explicitly identify what I'm looking to validate and was hoping there's a simpler way for terraform to pull information and in which case I can validate and use count.

Comment: That is not how terraform is supposed to work, no. You can always `import` resources but not in an automatic way.

Comment: Thanks. So how would I "import" AWS Config as an example. Is there any easier why to use count for AWS config?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/config_config_rule#import

Comment: Thanks, though what about AWS Config Recorder. Do I need to import that as well or does terraform just avoid the recorder if running and I only need to import the rules?